# How do percentiles work?

Tags: statistics

If I have 5 students (A-E) that score 80%, 70%, 70%, 60% and 50% on a test what percentiles do they fall in?

- A - 20th percentile (80%)
- B - 40th percentile (70%)
- C - 40th percentile (70%)
- D - 80th percentile (60%)
- E - 100th percentile (50%)

Is this correct?

Let me expand the question as I wasn't clear earlier: If A is in the top 20th percentile, are B and C in the top 40th percentile or top 60th percentile?

Comment: @Arturo - Perhaps this should be an answer.

Comment: when you ask questions like this, you should try to consult other sources, e.g. the Wikipedia article, first.  If they confuse you, ask about the thing that's confusing you.

Comment: You are misusing "percentile" as a synonym for "percent". They are *not* the same thing!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've got them backwards. The 20th percentile would be the level below which only 20% of the observations fall. Since 80% of the scores fall below A's score (four out of 5), then A is in the 80th percentile. Since 20% of the scores fall below D's score, then D is in the 20th percentile, not the 80th. See [Wikipedia's page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) on percentiles (it's rather rough, but the lead will do it).

**Edit:** You edited the question, so here goes the answer to that: 
It seems that you are not really asking about *percentiles*, but about **percents**. They are not the same thing. A is in the top 20 percent, but not "the top 20 percentile". By *definition*, **percentile** refers to how many quantities are *below*. It makes no sense to talk about "top 20 percentile".  Your intended question is about percents, not 'percentiles'.

To answer that: You have 5 people; A is the top, B and C are tied in second, D is in fourth, and E in fifth. A is certainly in the top 20% of the group, E in the bottom 20%; D and E are in the bottom 40%. A, B, and C are in the top 60% (not the top 40%); B, C, D, and E are in the bottom 80%. But you are using "percentile" wrong. If X is in the 40th percentile, then that means that 40% of the scores are below him; that would mean he is at the bottom of the top 60%. A is in the 80 percentile, B and C are in the 40th percentile, D is in the 20th percentile.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a z table, the percentiles would make more sense.  For example, mean IQ is 100 and the standard deviation is 15.  Someone in the 84th percentile would have an IQ of 115.

The z score is 1 found by

z = x - mean IQ/standard deviation

So,  z = 115 - 100/15 = 1

Depending on the type of z table you have (half the bell curve or not), you will see a series of percentages that correspond to any given z score.  If you have a z table that is based on half the bell curve, then the percentage (not percentile) is .3413  To get the percentile, you add .50 + .3413 given you 84th percentile.  Lind, Marchal and Wathen statistics textbooks are a great resource for getting a solid basic understanding of statistics.